# libc6-dev : Breaks: binutils (< 2.26) but 2.25-5+deb8u1 is to be installed

Tags: debian

I try to install some libs on Debian 8.9

```
apt-get install libnice-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: binutils (< 2.26) but 2.25-5+deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 7):

```
apt-get remove binutils
```

Should get you running.

Comment: Works. @see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/749076/installed-wrong-libc6-dev-version